# How to show that $\sqrt{n}(X_n - \mu) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, \sigma^2) \Rightarrow X_n \overset{p}{\to} \mu$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $\sqrt{n}(X_n - \mu) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, \sigma^2)$. I am trying to show that $X_n \overset{p}{\to} \mu$. By Markov's inequality 
\begin{align*}
P(|X_n - \mu| > \epsilon) &< \frac{E((X_n - \mu)^2)}{\epsilon^2} \\
&= \frac{E((\sqrt{n}(X_n - \mu))^2)}{n\epsilon^2}.
\end{align*}
but I'm not sure where to go from here. If someone could give a small hint about what to try I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem). Indeed since $1/\sqrt{n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ (in particular in probability) we have that)
$$
X_n - \mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\times \sqrt{n}(X_n - \mu)\overset{d}{\to} 0
$$
and in particular $X_n - \mu\to 0$ in probability as desired.

Comment: Convergence in distribution does not imply convergence in probability right?

Comment: @TheProofisTrivium It does if the limit is constant (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propB1)).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: $$\mathbb{P}[|X_n - \mu| \leq \epsilon] = \mathbb{P}[\sqrt{n}|X_n - \mu| \leq \sqrt{n}\epsilon] = \mathbb{P}[-\sqrt{n}\epsilon \leq \sqrt{n}(X_n - \mu) \leq \sqrt{n}\epsilon] = \mathbb{P}[\sqrt{n}(Y_n - \mu) \leq \sqrt{n}\epsilon] - \mathbb{P}[\sqrt{n}(Y_n - \mu)<-\sqrt{n}\epsilon]$$ Taking the limit gives $1$.